# Google bot return error 500 Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis, googlebot

Is there a way to check if a page returns a 500 error? Google has just dropped 3000 of our pages from index. Implemented some fix, but need to check if it worked. It is only going to crawl the site again next week.

Answer (score 1):

Google Webmaster Tools has a crawl statistics menu, where it will display crawl errors. It requires you to sign up, verify the site and then waiting until Google has crawled the site.

However, it has a 'view as googlebot' function which might help you as well.

I'd start there personally.

Answer (score 1):

Monitor all the things!

- [Apache log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)
- [elmah](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/)
- [Enable Trace Logging for Failed Requests (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725786%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Hope this helps (I know you need to verify it now that your fix works, so my answer is more of a future recommendation).